# An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator

Tags: css, installation

When I tried to modify Microsoft forefront Unified access login.asp page and pages that comes with it ,

I prepared my custom files for css; inc files ;  InstallAndDetect ..etc

but When i inserted those files under CustomUpdate folders i got this error :

*" An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. "*

I tried files i prepared before by putting them in the place of the default files propvided by the system.
Ofc the naming is respecting when using customupdate files!!

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue??

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have a proper picture of what exactly might have caused the problem in your case.

But I just went through resolving the same error message on my system (2012 R2, IIS 8) (while searching for the solution I came across your post)

And it turned out that what was causing my problems was the use of classic ASP parent paths (with "../" in them)

Switching to absolute and virtual paths solved the issue for me.

See here: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer.
Actually there was a bug with the product itself.
It didn't recognize the path to the CustomUpdate folder for any of custom folders in InternalSite folder. 
I had to ask for a hot fix from Microsoft support to be able to use customized files (CSS , asp, images ).
Once the fix was installed, everything was working fine and I was able to see the customization I have done to the login page.